# Vuetify components not found/loading in nuxt3 project

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3

1. Stack:
   node version: 19.9
   nuxt: "3.4.1"
   vuetify: "3.1.14"
2. Problem:
   After 3/4 hours of working on nuxt 3 project, vuetify components stopped being recognized and in console there is an error:
   [console push warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE2Za.png)
3. Code - nuxt settings

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: [
        'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass',
        '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css',
    ],
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify'],
    },

    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/i18n',
        '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    ],

    i18n: {
        lazy: true,
        langDir: 'locales',
        strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
        defaultLocale: 'en-Us',
        locales: [
            {
                code: 'en-Us',
                file: 'en-US.js',
                name: 'English(US)',
                iso: 'en-US',
            }
        ]
    },

    vite: {
        define: {
            'process.env.DEBUG': false,
        },
    },
    
});
```

**~/pluging/vuetify.ts**

```
import 'vuetify/styles';
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';
import { md1 } from 'vuetify/blueprints';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxt) => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        ssr: true,
        components,
        directives,
        blueprint: md1,
        theme: {
            defaultTheme: 'dark',
        }
    });
    
    nuxt.vueApp.use(vuetify);
});
```

**~/pages/index.vue**
[in vscode everything looks like good, I can see types etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTJHz.png)

I followed this tutorial: https://codybontecou.com/how-to-use-vuetify-with-nuxt-3.html.

As I mentioned, for some time it was working but then ... not sure what happened, maybe adding eslint coused this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was my mistake. Instead of having folder `plugins` I had folder named `plugin`